# adding rows with Nan values to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, nan

I want to insert rows with Nan values after each row

| index | values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 44 |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 51 |
| 3 | 66 |
| 4 | 23 |

DataFrame should look like this

| index | values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 44 |
| 1 | Nan |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | Nan |
| 4 | 51 |
| 5 | Nan |
| 6 | 66 |
| 7 | Nan |
| 8 | 23 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with DataFrame filled by `NaN`s and same indices and then use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)])
        .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True))
print (df)
   values
0    44.0
1     NaN
2    50.0
3     NaN
4    51.0
5     NaN
6    66.0
7     NaN
8    23.0
9     NaN
```

If need remove last missing value:

```
df = (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)])
        .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
        .iloc[:-1])
print (df)
   values
0    44.0
1     NaN
2    50.0
3     NaN
4    51.0
5     NaN
6    66.0
7     NaN
8    23.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
(df.assign(index=df['index']*2)
   .set_index('index')
   .reindex(range(len(df)*2))
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   index  values
0      0    44.0
1      1     NaN
2      2    50.0
3      3     NaN
4      4    51.0
5      5     NaN
6      6    66.0
7      7     NaN
8      8    23.0
9      9     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\baf03\\Downloads\\water-physical-stock-account-quarterly-1995-2020-CSV.csv")

df.loc[0,"yq"]=np.nan

df
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!